# Maximizing/minimizing product of output and response

Tags: regression, optimization

I need to optimize based on an objective function that is non-standard, as far as I know. If the predictors are $X$, output of the model is $\hat y$, and response is $y$, my objective is essentially:

$$j = \sum( \hat y \cdot y ). $$

Minimized it would just be $-j$. Does anyone know of an existing approach to optimization/regression that uses an objective like this? $\hat y\cdot y$ is equivalent to what is called the margin in machine learning, but I cannot find any work that discusses optimizing this directly.

I could obviously just cram this into a global optimizer but I am interested in any work  that is pre-existing.

Comment: why do you state that this objective function is non-standard? what is the functional form of \hat{y}|X?